# Hive - Extract data from nested Json

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I have table called  newdata

```
create external table newdata
(
data string
)
location 'something'
```

`select data from string limit 1`

```
{ "user": { "name": "default", "education": { "schoome": "abc", "college": "def" } }
```

I need to show this result as

| user | name | school | college|

|--------|---------|----------|-----------|

Comment: `schoome`? :-) ...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to extract `"user"`

Comment: P.s. This seems to be  a simple case. Did you have any special issues with it?

Comment: Dudu Thanks, I have a big analysis, I used this to avoid huge select statement________ SELECT

json_extract_scalar(item, '$.name') as name,
 json_extract_scalar(item, '$.education') as name

FROM newdata
cross join unnest(cast(json_extract(data, '$.user'))) as i(item),,,,,
anyhow thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  json_extract_scalar (data,'$.user.name')              as name
       ,json_extract_scalar (data,'$.user.education.school')  as school
       ,json_extract_scalar (data,'$.user.education.college') as college

from    newdata
```